# macro to create chart with x axis values excel

Tags: excel, vba

im new to vba and this will create most of the chart i want but the x axis i would like to have a2:a133 be the x axis

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$S$1:$S$133")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
With ActiveChart.Parent
.Height = 500
.Width = 1050
.Top = 1
.Left = 1
End With
```

i have tried adding the line

```
activeChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
"='CancNonPay Timing Report 09.26.'!$A$2:$A$133"
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(Range("$A$1:$A$133"), Range("$S$1:$S$133")), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

But also it looks like you're adding the chart on a new sheet, and both ranges in the line above will refer to this sheet, not the sheet that was active before inserting the new sheet.

So maybe this:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(Range("'CancNonPay Timing Report 09.26.'!$A$1:$A$133"), _
    Range("'CancNonPay Timing Report 09.26.'!$S$1:$S$133")), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```